# Hidden Markov Model for anomaly detection

Tags: outliers, hidden-markov-model, anomaly-detection

In Hidden Markov Model, it is possible to compute probability of observation sequence by applying forward algorithm given learned model. We can detect anomaly sequences by this algorithm simply by looking at low probability values. The problem is that we can only use this approach only for sequences of the same length.

Is there any invariant to length method to compute the anomaly degree of the sequence?

I only have sequences of normal behavior for training model.

Comment: Can you model an anomaly as a state?  If so, then you can just expand the HMM to include the "anomaly state".  Possible reasons why not include:  the duration of the system remaining in the "anomaly state" isn't distributed geometric (can be overcome with some additional complexity), and an inability to specify the distribution of outputs given that the system is in the anomaly state.

Comment: @jbowman, No, I cannot. I do not have labeled data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Hidden Markov Model, once fitted, can run on an input sequence of any length. However if you to to compute a distance / anomaly score by the output probabilities with one or more known sequences of particular, then the variable length may need to be handled.

One alternative is to use statistical aggregates before computing the distance, such as median/mean etc. Another alternative, which will do much better for dilations and translations in time, is to apply [Dynamic Time Warping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping).